# 複数のライセンスがリポジトリに混在するソースの利用時に適用されるライセンスはどれか

Tags: ライセンス

GitHubから[epd7in5.py](https://github.com/soonuse/gdew075t8_7.5inch_e-paper/blob/master/raspberrypi/python/epd7in5.py)というライブラリファイル1つだけを、自身の新規プロジェクトに含めて開発を始めようとしています。

上記のソースコード(epd7in5.py)の冒頭に`MITライセンス`が書かれています。
ただしその[親フォルダ](https://github.com/soonuse/gdew075t8_7.5inch_e-paper/tree/master/raspberrypi/python)のreadme.txtには`修正BSDライセンス`が書かれています。
そしてさらにリポジトリの[トップ](https://github.com/soonuse/gdew075t8_7.5inch_e-paper)のLICENSEファイルには`GPL-3.0`が書かれていて、GitHubリポジトリのトップページには`GPL-3.0`のアイコンが表示されています。

簡単に図示すると下記のような構造です。

```
+ gdew075t8_7.5inch_e-paper
| - LICENSE(GPL-3.0)
| + raspberrypi
    + python
    | - epd7in5.py(MIT)
    | - readme(修正BSD)
```

この場合、ソースコード(epd7in5.py)を二次利用する際に適用されるライセンスは何でしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ソースコード(epd7in5.py)を二次利用する際に適用されるライセンスは何

まず gdew075t8_7.5inch_e-paper は GPLv3 で MIT ライセンスと互換があるため 
MIT ライセンスであるソースコード(epd7in5.py)を
リンクして 全体として GPLv3 で 公開しています。

```
メインアプリ gdew075t8_7.5inch_e-paper : GPLv3
  - リンクするライブラリ epd7in5.py : MIT
```

互換性が認められないライセンスのライブラリは GPLv3 のアプリにリンクする事はできません。

次に 質問者の作成した プログラムが MIT ライセンスをリンクした場合ですが、

```
質問者の作ったメインアプリ : ?ライセンス
  - リンクするライブラリ epd7in5.py : MIT
```

MIT ライセンス は かなり緩い ライセンスなので、あらゆるライセンスが 適用可能です。
GPLv3 にすることも可能ですし、MIT にすることも可能です。
また ソースコードを非公開とするライセンスにも可能です。

#### 注意点

上記の 理論が成り立つのは  epd7in5.py が **本当に MIT ライセンスだと確認**できた場合です。
ソースのヘッダ部分の記載だけでは、改変した人が、実は GPL な コードが紛れ込ませていて
記載していませんでした。
なんてトラブルも発生する可能性があります。

epd7in5.py を GitHub で検索すると 原著者のものと思われるもの
https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper/blob/b488e9609d1ad84f272d0fe9b70a7519b4b5dbee/RaspberryPi%26JetsonNano/python/lib/waveshare_epd/epd7in5.py

があり、ちょっと内容が違いますが、こちらを 持ってきた方が安心だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

MIT や 修正BSD は GPL と互換性が認められているフリーソフトウェアのライセンスです。
ご参考）https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ja.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses

GPLによって、MITも修正BSDも の条件が包括されていますので GPLv3 を選んでおけば問題はないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

著作物の利用許諾(ライセンシング)は、著作権に基づいて書作権保持者が行います。

(表記が全て間違いなく著作権保持者の意図通りだとすると)
今回の `epd7in5.py` の著作権は Waveshare社であり、提示されているライセンスは MIT なので、利用者として従うべきは **MITライセンス** ということになります。

---

ただ今回の件は全部作者が同じ方(Waveshare社のYuhuiさん？)のように見えるので、厳密な意図を知る必要があるのであればこの方に問い合わせてみるのも手かもしれません。
(最終的にはあるライセンスに統一しようと考えていたが、書き換えるのを忘れていた、みたいなこともあり得るかなと思いました。)

Comment: 再配布されたときのライセンスが元々のライセンスと異なるからといって、オリジナルのライセンスが勝手に変更されたりすることはない(なぜなら再配布者が著作権を持っているわけではないから)、ということです。